# Svelte js How to pass styles to child (with passability to override)

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

In svelte, I want to write components in BEM style, so component was stylized by its own styles and then positioned from parent's styles

The problem: to do this, I need to put the component in a wrapper `div` and then position that `div` in parent like this

```html
// App.svelte
<script>
import Component from './Component.svelte'
</script>

<div class="positioned_div">
  <Component />
</div>
```

What would create unnecessary nesting

Another way is to use selector with :global in `<style>`, but that in not an option because I want to be able to override child's styles.

Instead, I wish I could just pass a classname to component like in React module

```html
<script>
import Component from './Component.svelte
</script>

<Component class="positioningC" />

<styles>
.positioningClass {/* Some styles */}
</styles>
```

and child component

```html
<script>
let className
export { className as class }
</script>

<div class={`componentStyle ${className}`}></div>

<style>
.componentStyle {/* some styles */}
</style>
```

Is there a way to get a hash-classname which Svelte creates from the parent and pass it to the child? Are there some packages for styling that could accomplish the same thing (like styled JSX and etc for React)?

Comment: Mystery abbreviation BEM?  Oops, I see you are new here. Welcome to StackOverflow (SO).

Comment: Depending on the number of declarations you want to pass, maybe using `--style-props` could be an option https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives---style-props

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$$props` to access all properties passed from the parent component.  You can use spread operator to merge props from parent.

`Child.svelte`

```html
<div {...$props}>

</div>
```

or

```html
<div class="child-class {...$props.class}">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I found a couple of packages for this specific purpose: @naumstory/svelte-true-css-modules and svelte-preprocess-cssmodules

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@naumstory/svelte-true-css-modules
https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-preprocess-cssmodules